# Is there a way to use sagemaker lifecycle configuration to run an EMR cluster on notebook start

Tags: boto3, amazon-emr, amazon-sagemaker

I would like to start an EMR cluster every time a sagemaker notebook is started.
However, I have find out that Lifecycle configuration scripts cannot run for longer than 5 minutes. Sadly my EMR cluster take more then 5 minutes to be up. This is a problem as I need to wait for the cluster to be up in order to retrieve the master ip address (that ip address is then used to configure the connection between sagemaker notebbok and the cluster).

Below an extract of the code which is run into the lifecycle configuration script.

Is there someone out there which have faced a similar problem and found a solution ?

````
job_flow_id = client.run_job_flow(**CLUSTER_CONFIG)['JobFlowId']

...
...

# Retrieve private Ip of master node for later use
master_instance = client.list_instances(ClusterId=job_flow_id, InstanceGroupTypes=['MASTER'])['Instances'][0]
master_private_ip = master_instance['PrivateIpAddress']

# Send to sagemaker the config file in order to tell him how to communicate with spark
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
file_object = s3.get_object(Bucket='dataengine', Key='emr/example_config.json')
data = json.loads(file_object['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
data['kernel_python_credentials']['url'] = 'http://{}:8998'.format(master_private_ip)
data['kernel_scala_credentials']['url'] = 'http://{}:8998'.format(master_private_ip)
data['kernel_r_credentials']['url'] = 'http://{}:8998'.format(master_private_ip)

with open('./sparkmagic/config.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also consider using [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) in Lifecycle config to execute your script in background, so you don't get blocked by 5-min limit.

Let us know if there's anything else you need assistance of.

Thanks,

Han

Answer (score 0):

AWS CloudFormation will automate all of that for you, and let you pass the IP address as well.

As you seem to like Python, I'd recommend Troposphere: https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere. Write Python code, generate a CloudFormation template, run it :)

Julien (AWS)

Comment: Great ! Just can't find where to specify the master ip address in troposphere, any ideas ?

Comment: One idea would be to attach a tag to the notebook instance, referencing the IP address. You could then read the tag and connect. Maybe someone else has another idea? :)